# How to exclude folder name regardless of path in bash?

Tags: find, regular-expression

I am trying to exclude folders from being searched in for files. It actually works relatively well.

My code looks like this: `find . -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex "(./Scripts/testfolder)" -prune -o -type f -print`

My problem is, however, that I would like to exclude all occurences of folder name regardless of path. Basically I want to remove ***./Scripts/*** part and just ignore testfolder folder, wherever it is. Can it be done by improving the regular expression?

When I run: `find . -type d -regextype posix-extended -regex "(testfolder)" -prune -o -type f -print`, the folder is entered and files are fetched.

Answer (score 1):

You need to realize that the `-name` option in `find` really refers to the `basename` of the pertinent object being referred to. Hence, we can look up the directory by name and then prune it:

```
find . -type d -name 'testfolder' -prune -o -type f -print
```